# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? (Это мысль, не высказанная персонажем вслух)

Tags: пунктуация, несобственно-прямая-речь

Тот отвернулся: «Не мой клиент».

Answer (score 2):

**Тот отвернулся: не мой клиент. Тот отвернулся – не мой клиент.**

Это БСП со значение изъяснения, но изъяснительная часть представлена как несобственно-прямая речь.

**Несобственно-прямая речь**   – это часть текста, передающая слова, мысли, чувства персонажа. Этот прием часто используется в художественной литературе и публицистике, когда автору нужно показать своего героя как бы изнутри, дать читателю услышать его внутренний голос.